# Bounds for $S_N(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(\alpha n)$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analysis

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N$ be a positive integer. Are there any good bounds known for the absolute value of the sum
$$
S_N(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(\alpha n)
$$
for $N$ large and which are uniform in $\alpha$? That is, what can we say about $\|S_N\|_{\infty}$? Clearly $\|S_N\|_\infty \leq N$. But can we do better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Notice that
\begin{align*}
S_{N}(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(\alpha n) = \mathrm{Im}\sum_{n=1}^{N}e^{i\alpha n} = \mathrm{Im}\left[\frac{e^{i\alpha} - e^{i(N+1)\alpha}}{1 - e^{i\alpha}}\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. If I'm correct, the imaginary part of that is $(\cos(\alpha/2) - \cos(\alpha(N + 1/2)))/2\sin(\alpha/2)$. When $\alpha/2$ is far from an integer multiple of $\pi$, the absolute value of this is at most $|\csc(\alpha/2)|$. How about the case when $\alpha/2$ is close to an integer multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: You mean $\alpha = 2k\pi$? In such case, $\sin(\alpha n) = \sin(2kn\pi) = 0$. Hence $S_{N}(\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: Of course, but I didn't mean the case when $\alpha$ is precisely $0 \pmod{\pi}$. I meant in a neighbourhood of that, with the radius of the neighbourhood small in terms of $N$. For example, for $\alpha$ close to 0, the numerator has essentially a Taylor expansion of the form $\alpha^2 N^2 + O(\alpha^4 N^4)$ while the denominator is essentially $\alpha + O(\alpha^3)$ (I'm omitting some constants here). Thus for $\alpha$ close enough to $0$, the imaginary part above is essentially $\alpha N^2$. This is smaller than $N$ for $\alpha \leq 1/N$.

Comment: But in the case when $\alpha \geq 1/N$, the bound $1/\alpha$ gives $N$, the trivial bound. So no improvements from what I see...

Comment: Thus we have good bounds when $\alpha \pmod{\pi}$ is either much larger or much smaller than $1/N$, but the problem is the case when $\alpha \pmod{\pi} \asymp 1/N$.